# PyQt : How to change a label text from a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

My question is :
How to change a label (or other graphic elements) from a package?
The idea is to lighten my main program.
Thanks!

ex main program :

```
#../mainprogram.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from ui import Ui_MainWindow
from package import update

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # label from .ui -> .py
        self.ui.label_1.setText("need to change this")

    def update_label(self):
        self.update = update.label_update()
```

ex package :

```
#../package/update.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def label_update():
    self.ui.label_1.setText("no problem")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do is pass the instance of the object through to the function. Consider:

```
def label_update():
    self.ui.label_1.setText("no problem")
```

In this scope, we don't know what `self` is because it's not been defined. However, if you pass through `self`:

```
#../mainprogram.py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def update_label(self):
        self.update = update.label_update(self)


#../package/update.py
def label_update(obj): #obj is the object self
    obj.ui.label_1.setText("no problem")
```

We are updating the object that was passed into the function.

Comment: It works great, thank you !
In my case, I need to store the above procedure that changes a pixmap from green to red.
Is that the best way to lighten the main program ?